# JSON file not all caught in a Jquery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a problem sending my JSON file parameters through HTTP POST method.
The file is properly generated but only part of it is sent.

```
       $("#catalogOfService").jqGrid('navGrid',"#catalogOfService_pager").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#catalogOfService_pager', {
        caption: "Export to Excel",
        onClickButton: function () {
            var json = $("#catalogOfService").getRowData();
            var name = "report_catalogue";
            console.log(json);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "ExportCatalogueExcell.php",
                data: {
                          name: name, 
                          data: json,
                },

                success: function(result)
                {
                },
                success: function(e){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log(yeah);
                        window.open("../tmp/" + name + '.csv');
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about the specific problem you are having

Comment: what is in`ExportCatalogueExcell.php`?

Comment: two `success` callbacks....?

Comment: I'm using jquery to send a JSON file in order to generate a CSV file. I get the JSON from a jqgrid data that contains more than 230 lines .The problem that only 82 line of the table are sent in the HTTP POST method

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Yes , the console.log(json) shows all my data(233 lines)  and  in the  POST HTTP  there is only 82.

Comment: Given the organization of your code I would imagine that it throws errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update this part:

```
data: JSON.stringify(json)
```

`JSON.stringify()` converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, in other words, it converts a JavaScript object to JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string. And, this JSON text is what you need as the data in your `POST` request.

Comment: I think there are a lot more problems than this with the OP's code.

Comment: It would also be good to explain why this line needs to be updated.